# Delphi element alignment - center

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe6

There seems to be `align` property that works really well, but is is possible to align element so all elements on panel would be aligned to center all on bottom of each other if they all have less than size of container? Something like top-center-center.

Something like this:

[image: Something like this]

Or at least horizontally, and vertically they can have 100%.

Comment: This can be done by using an intermediate container... layouts with FireMonkey and the latest versions of Delphi... or another TPanel with no borders.

Comment: How? There is no `alCenter`...

Comment: Please add the Delphi version and platform (VCL/FM)

Comment: If you disable all of the flags in a control's `Anchors` property, the control ends up aligning itself centered to its `Parent`  So put the elements into an autosized `TPanel` or `TFrame` container, and then disable that container's `Anchors`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau didn't work.

Comment: @FlashThunder: Works fine for me when I try it. But the container has to be in the center to begin with, then it will stay centered (more accurately, it will stay relative to its starting position). A more reliable solution would be to set the container's `Align` to `alCustom` and the use its parent contaier's `OnAlignPosition` event to keep the child container centered.  See the answer I posted.

Comment: Ah I understand, then it's not what I need.

Answer (score 12):

Put the elements into their own container, such as a `TPanel` or `TFrame`, that is a child of your main container.  Set the child container's `Align` property to `alCustom` and use the parent container's `OnAlignPosition` event to keep the child container centered to itself:

```
// Panel1 is the Parent container for the child panel...
procedure TMyForm.Panel1AlignPosition(Sender: TWinControl; Control: TControl;
  var NewLeft, NewTop, NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer; var AlignRect: TRect;
  AlignInfo: TAlignInfo);
begin
  if Control = ChildPanel then
  begin
    NewLeft := AlignRect.Left + ((AlignRect.Width - Control.Width) div 2);
    NewTop := AlignRect.Top + ((AlignRect.Height - Control.Height) div 2);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Oh thanx, didn't know how to use this `alCustom`

Comment: The alternative is to eliminate the child container, and then set `alCustom` on the elements themselves, and then the parent container's `OnAlignPosition` can position the elements directly as needed.

Comment: This center alignment with alCustom occurs only at the runtime. There are a way to also occurs at design time like alClient, alLeft and so on..?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for coding anything. Just place panels and other visual objects in the right way an set the properties of the visual objects as shown here:

```
Align: alNone or alCustom
and
Anchors: none (akLeft=False, akTop=False, akRight=False, akBottom=False)
```

Than and an object will stay at its relative horizontal and vertical position. If you place it in the middle in a container it will stay centered.

To center it only vertical set

```
Align: alNone or alCustom
and
Anchors: akTop=True OR akBottom=True
```

To center it only horizontal set

```
Align: alNone or alCustom
and
Anchors: akLeft=True OR akRight=True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can center the control with this little procedure

```
procedure CenterControl( AControl : TControl );
begin
  if Assigned( AControl.Parent )
  then
    begin
      // remove alignment
      AControl.Align := alNone;
      // remove the anchors
      AControl.Anchors := [];
      // center on parent
      AControl.Left := ( AControl.Parent.ClientWidth - AControl.Width ) div 2;
      AControl.Top := ( AControl.Parent.ClientHeight - AControl.Height ) div 2;
    end
  else
    raise Exception.Create( 'Control needs a Parent!' );
end;
```

If the parent gets resized the control will always be centered, as long as you did not change its size.

Comment: It would be better to use the VCL's native alignment capabilities. If nothing else, a parent control knows about all of its child controls, even custom aligned ones, and calculates the areas where they are allowed to be aligned relative to.

Answer (score 0):

In RAD 10+ there is control TRelativePanel which has AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel and AlignHorisontalCenterWithPanel life-save options (and other useful capabilities).

You can also position invisilble line or dot in the center and build other controls around it with TRelativePanel provided properties Above/Below/etc.
Worth to mention, control is made on top level Embarcadero quality standards (crashes only in design mode).